# How to get difference of price of today and yesterday price for a product and also find out whether product was available yesterday or not?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table "price_hist" in AmazonRedshift (Postgresql) which has product and price data for 10 countries on daily basis twice a day. I want only latest data for each day for each product

For Example below is the table

```
Country Product Price(string)   Created_On
US      001     $2,300     2015/02/16 00:46:20
US      001     $2,300     2015/02/16 13:27:12
DK      006     kr1,700    2015/02/16 00:46:20    
DK      006     kr1,700    2015/02/16 13:27:12 

US      002     $5,300     2015/02/15 00:46:20
US      002     $5,300     2015/02/15 13:27:12
US      001     $2,200     2015/02/15 00:46:20
US      001     $2,200     2015/02/15 13:27:12
DK      007     kr28       2015/02/15 00:46:20    
DK      007     kr28       2015/02/15 13:27:12 

US      001     $2,100     2015/02/14 00:46:20
US      002     $5,200     2015/02/14 13:27:12
DK      007     kr9,100    2015/02/14 00:46:20    
DK      007     kr9,100    2015/02/14 13:27:12
```

Now I want a query which should show always data for today and yesterday with price difference and with a flag for product whether it was available yesterday or not.
Required Output :

```
Country Product P_today  p_yesterday p_change  flag   created_on
US      001     2300     2200           100    Both     2015/02/16 13:27:12
US      002     0        5300         -5300    Removed  2015/02/15 13:27:12
DK      006     1700     0             1700    Added    2015/02/16 13:27:12    
DK      007     0        9100         -9100    Removed  2015/02/15 13:27:12
```

where column P_Change  - Show price changes between today's and yesterday's products.
             flag - Create a column to reflect new products added in Today's data and the ones which got removed.

Comment: Can you store currency denomination separately from currency value?

Comment: You say you have AmazonRedshift (Postgresql), so why tag MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry Data is like that only in table with currency and thousand separator, If it is only for US I can handle it using SUBSRTING function, but I have no idea how to do it for other countries as well.

Comment: This problem is made really (and unnecessarily) hard by this data model.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes really this is going to be very difficult , anyway for now will remove currency from column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like that:

```
select country,product,P_today,P_yesterday, (P_today - P_yesterday) as P_change , 
    CASE 
    WHEN P_today > 0 and P_yesterday > 0 then 'both'
    WHEN P_today = 0 and P_yesterday > 0 then 'removed'
    WHEN P_today > 0 and P_yesterday = 0 then 'added'
    END
from
(select 
    isnull(q1.country,q2.country) as country,isnull(q1.product, q2.product) as product ,isnull(q1.price, 0) as P_today, isnull(q2.price,0) as P_yesterday
    from 
    (select * from product where created_on in (select max(created_on) from product where date_trunc('day', created_on) = '2015-02-16 00:00:00+00' group by product,country)) as q1 
    full outer join 
    (select * from product where created_on in (select max(created_on) from product where date_trunc('day', created_on) = '2015-02-15 00:00:00+00' group by product,country)) as q2 
    on q1.country = q2.country and q1.product = q2.product )
```

I tested it and it gave me something similar to what you are looking for, see below:

```
 country | product | p_today | p_yesterday | p_change |  case   
---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---------
 US      | 001     |    2300 |        2300 |        0 | both
 US      | 002     |       0 |        2300 |    -2300 | removed
 DK      | 006     |     700 |           0 |      700 | added
 DK      | 007     |       0 |        2300 |    -2300 | removed
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The date is harcoded still but it should be easy to pass it dynamically if you pass it as a parameter.